# FullCalendar month tabs

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar but I need the months to be displayed above the calendar starting from September 2011 to September 2012. When you click on a month it displays that month's events. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: How are you going to be displaying the months?

Answer (score 0):

In their [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) you will the [gotoDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) function.

```
.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year [, month, [ date ]] )
```

(0 based integer values)

Comment: I've seen that but where in the fullcalendar.js would I go about that?

Comment: @Chris Wherever you use `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({/*whatever in here*/})` to initialize the calendar would be where you call that function. e.g. `$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', 2011, 7, 8 )` for today.

Comment: Is there a way to have something custom to appear in an area of the header?

Comment: @Chris idk :P sounds like you should post another question... I've never used fullCalendar. XD